# Inserting Function into SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

Brand new to functions. Received function from someone else to solve for html tags in a data pull. No idea how to incorporate this code into my query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[mcl_RemoveVisionMemoFormat] 
(@String NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
 RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
AS 
BEGIN 
declare @start int, 
        @end int, 
        @length int 

while charindex('<', @string) > 0 and charindex('>', @string, charindex('<', 
@string)) > 0 
begin 
    select  @start  = charindex('<', @string),  
            @end    = charindex('>', @string, charindex('<', @string)) 
    select @length = (@end - @start) + 1 

    if @length > 0 
    begin 
        select @string = stuff(@string, @start, @length, '') 
        end 
    end 

return replace(@string , '&nbsp;' , ' ') 
END
```

Above function needs to be added to a basic SELECT statement

```
SELECT LD.WBS1 as [Project Number], LD.Name, LD.Comment, LD.TransDate as 
[Comment Date]
FROM LD
WHERE (((LD.Comment) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY LD.TransDate DESC;
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Which column has the html tags?

Comment: None...I am not the dba. I'm just pulling data into Power BI.

Comment: The column with HTML is LD.Comment

Comment: `(((LD.Comment) Is Not Null))` you could have added some more parenthesis

Comment: That function makes me sad. Scalar functions are so bad for performance, then this one has a while loop inside of it. It looks like all it is doing is replacing every instance of < > and nbsp; with an empty string?

Comment: You are stuffing into the same string you are removing from?

Comment: Do you need the following - `SELECT LD.Comment OriginalComment, [dbo].[mcl_RemoveVisionMemoFormat](LD.Comment) ClearedComment FROM LD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is strictly how to use a scalar function in a query using a column as a parameter

To do this, you just add the function to the select statement and pass in the column.

```
Select [schema].[ScalarFunction](column) as [ColumnName] from [schema].table
```

For the query you provided, you just add the function [dbo].[mcl_RemoveVisionMemoFormat] followed by the column name LD.Comment in parenthesis

```
SELECT LD.WBS1 as [Project Number], LD.Name, LD.Comment, LD.TransDate as [Comment Date], [dbo].[mcl_RemoveVisionMemoFormat](LD.Comment) as [CommentWithoutVisionMemoFormat]
FROM LD
WHERE LD.Comment IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LD.TransDate DESC;
```